# When editing in ExAdmin, how do you retain the value when defined as a collection dropdown

Tags: elixir, exadmin

When editing in ExAdmin all the fields that are defined with a collection loses their value. How do you keep them when editing?

```
form vehicle do
  inputs do
    input vehicle, :vehicle_type, collection: Enum.map(VehicleTypeEnum.__enum_map__, fn a -> Atom.to_string(a) end)
```

[image]

Selecting and creating works, but when I click edit it goes back to Select a Vehicle Type for each of the dropdowns.

**[update]**
The problem seems to be that I'm using EctoEnum. The collection dropdown works as expected when using on a field that is defined as string. The vehicle_type field is defined as VehicleTypeEnum

models/vehicle.ex

```
schema "vehicles" do
  field :vehicle_type, VehicleTypeEnum
  field :display_name, :string
```

ecto_enums.ex

```
import EctoEnum
defenum VehicleTypeEnum, :vehicle_type, [:car, :bus, :truck]
```

Is there a way to get around this and still use EctoEnum with ExAdmin collection dropdown? Keeping them as atoms didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that you are saving this value from these fields properly? I just checked ex_admin in my project and it works correctly for values from collections.

Comment: You are right. Tried adding a collection to a different field that is specified as string and it works for that field. Problem seems to be that my enums are entered as strings but are saved as atoms? And that then can't be compared back?

Comment: I use EctoEnum and it works fine. Does your changeset allow to change these values?

Comment: Yes, and removing the collection part and typing in car, bus or truck text input field works, the value stays when I edit.  
I also tried changing the vehicle_type list to contain strings instead of atoms but that didn't change the behaviour

Comment: The vehicle_type value is stored as an atom. I suspect that it's because I convert them to a list of strings that makes ex_admin unable to compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you might not browse the collection properly, because ex_admin requires to receive there a tuple of params, where the value is string. Please try to rewrite your code like from this:

```
Enum.map(VehicleTypeEnum.__enum_map__, fn a -> Atom.to_string(a) end)
```

to this:

```
Enum.map(
  VehicleTypeEnum.__enum_map__, 
  fn a -> 
    case a do
      {key, value} -> {key, to_string(value)}
      value -> {value, to_string(value)}
    end
  end
)
```